# counting float digits (hw) C

Tags: c, count, floating-point, double, scanf

I need to count digits from a `float` number and keep the number.
I can use `scanf()` with `%f` or `%c` but not `%s`, and I can use `getchar()`.

I can use getchar but I will loose the number.

Comment: [`scanf("...%n")`](https://ideone.com/fFmzK3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why will you lose the number with `getchar`?

1. Read characters with getchar until you hit whitespace/enter/end of input
2. Collect them all into a single string
3. Use `strtod` to make sure it's a valid floating point value
4. Count digits in the string - either before, or after the point, whatever you need.

If you're limited to only `getchar`:

1. Read chars one by one with `getchar`
2. Keep a state of where you are in the number: before decimal point, at decimal point, or after
3. Keep counting the digits as long as it's a valid floating point number (i.e. 1 or more digits, then optionally a decimal point with 1 or more digits after it)
4. Collect the digits into a floating point number by shifting powers of 10 (i.e. before decimal point multiply by 10.0 and add new number, after decimal point divide by a growing power of 10 and add).

Comment: sorry if i wasnt clear, i cant use strings. i can only  save a char(only one at a time) or a number (limited to using only scanf and getchar)

Comment: updated my answer, HTH. as this is a HW question, to get more help you should really post some code of your own and note exactly what you're having a problem with

Comment: To parse 0.123 is it better to read up the "123" part as an integer and divide it by 1000 in one step. Since none of 0.1, 0.02 or 0.003  are representable as IEEE 754 floats, your method accumulates more rounding errors than necessary.

Comment: @Pascal is right here - so if numerical errors matter you may want to modify the solution you submit

Answer (score 0):

As I see you got your answer, but is this works for you too ?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char *str = new char[30];
    float flt;
    int count = 0;

    scanf( "%f", &flt);
    printf( "number you entered is: %f\n", flt);
    sprintf(str, "%f", flt );

    for( ;str[count] != '\0'; count++ );

    printf( "%f have %d digits", flt, count-1);
    return 0;
}
```