# C: How to count digits of multiple digit integers using while loop?

Tags: c, scanf, do-while

```
int main(){
        int cardnum;
        int count = 0;
        do{
            printf("Enter your 16-digit Credit Card Number!\n");
            scanf(" %d", &cardnum);
            while(cardnum>0)
            {
                cardnum = cardnum / 10;
                count++;
            }
        }while( count != 16);
    }
```

so i am trying to make a program that asks you to insert your 16 digits of your CC and if you do not put 16 digits it keeps asking you till you do.

for some reason i get an infinite loop.
can smb explain?

Comment: A 32bit int cannot hold a 16 digit number.

Comment: Read it as a string.

Comment: What values are you inputting? And which loop do you think is infinete (there are two in your code)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting float digits (hw) C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988160/counting-float-digits-hw-c)

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting your `count` to 0 at each input attempt.

```
int main(){
        int cardnum;
        int count = 0;
        do{
            count = 0; /* Added this */
            printf("Enter your 16-digit Credit Card Number!\n");
            scanf(" %d", &cardnum);
            while(cardnum>0)
            {
                cardnum = cardnum / 10;
                count++;
            }
        }while( count != 16);
    }
```

[Edit: This is incorrect.] Although, I think you can check `scanf()`'s return value for the number of characters read. That might be easier.

Finally, there's that issue of an `int` being unable to hold a 16 digit number in it.

Comment: so should i do double? so it can hold more? also what do you mean with how do i do it with scanf

Comment: Check `long`'s range, that may suffice.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't return the number of characters read; it returns the number of successful *arguments* read. For the given single `%d` , a successful result would be `1`.

Comment: I stand corrected, but leaving the answer as is to not confuse future readers who'll have to figure out your comment otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

On most systems, int will not hold 16 digit numbers. It is usually 32 bit, and will store up to 9 digit number).

Luckily, 64 bit integer can hold 19 digits (18 digits if signed). (Almost) any decent Linux will support 64 bit integers. Few changes to the OP code:

- Change 'cardnum' to 'long long int count' (long int is sometimes 32)
- Change scanf format to '%lld') ;
- Change the 'count' loop to use temporary variable, otehrwise you loose the original card num. Something like:

```
   long long int check_num = cardnum ;
   for (count=0 ; check_num > 0 ; count++) check_num /= 10 ;
```